Does this capacitor look broken to you?
My laptop has been working perfectly for about a year, with over 300 battery cycles. Yesterday, it suddenly black-screened during boot, specifically at the last stage where the network service is starting. This makes me think it's not a software or BIOS issue.
I took it to a repair shop, and they suggested it might be a motherboard short circuit. To find the short circuit, I touched the motherboard to find any hot spots. The only part I found heating up was the power management unit. There is a small capacitor there that looks suspiciously broken.
The power management unit heats up only when the charger is connected, not with the internal battery. However, the laptop still won't start with either power source. All the units in that area get a bit warm, so I can't be sure if the suspicious chip is the only one overheating. The whole part that is circled in red is making a bit of heat
The orange colored tiny capacitor next to the label "PU702" is what I think is broken:

Update Edit: The microscope confirms that the capacitor has burned which cause one side of the welding material be burned out and therefore disconnect from the motherboard
PCB Components naming system:
C: Capacitor
R: Resistor
L: Inductor
Q: Transistor
D: Diode
U: Integrated Circuit (IC)
J: Connector
TP: Test Point
SW: Switch
Note that PU is meant by Power ralated IC (P=power U=IC)






"they suggested it might be a motherboard short circuit" - I heard several non-technical persons use "short circuit" as a catch-all term to describe any/every electrical problem. IOW you got a worthless evaluation. A real short circuit would typically be accompanied with overheating and smoke. An open circuit is just as likely as a short circuit, many people are not familiar with that term.*

Nice to know that, I can confirm that there isn't any smoke or overheating; infact the heat is very low.

Actually that (tan color) component appears to be a capacitor (not a "chip" nor "resistor"), and seems to have discoloration between the adjacent IC (marked X20PPD). Is it burn marks? Is the capacitor intact on the bottom end (facing the IC)?

The bottom looks completely normal, and the color change is exacally what made I thought it's broken as well, but after I scratch it, it went away but not completely. Also I can notice a tiny blank "hole" on the "capacitor", though the hole is really tiny

To get down to the component level requires equipment and expertise that likely is beyond most computer sales-point shops. A capacitance meter is needed, and the part might need to be desoldered to measure. And without the schematic, reverse-engineering is very difficult. BTW, either a completely open circuit or a completely shorted circuit would be at ambient temperature, because no power is dropped across either.

@sawdust What made you think that it is a capacitor, how did you deduce it?

@james - I inspected other boards that I have, and they have silk-screened component information. Similar looking, tan-colored components are marked as Cnnn, i.e. capacitors. It's the black-bodied components that are marked Rnnn, i.e. resistors.

@sawdust thank you very much, I just confirmed that it's a capacitor with some measure

I can confirm that the two orange "chips" were in fact a capacitor.
The problem was caused by a motherboard short circuit (which was caused by wet weather or water than accidentally get on motherboard).
The short circuit is which makes the capacitor to burn up and melted the soldering material which makes the capacitor disconnected from motherboard as well as one of the IC.
After soldering them back on, the motherboard is fixed. This means that no component on the motherboard is actually broken, they are just disconnected from the motherboard, I didn't even need to buy new capacitor nor IC.


The orange colored tiny "chip" next to the label "PU702" is what I think is broken:

That tan-colored component is most likely a capacitor (not a "chip" nor "resistor"), and seems to have discoloration (burn marks?) between the adjacent IC marked X20PPD.

According to an Aliexpress offering, that X20PPD chip seems to be related to the NX20P5090UKAZ, which is described as "an advanced 5 A unidirectional power switch for USB PD".
A failure of a power component is consistent with the board/trace discoloration (burn marks?). That IC is surface mount, and very difficult to replace/repair; there are 15 solder ball/pads underneath the chip.
You may have located the failure spot, and the capacitor and IC are obtainable at reasonable price. The condition of the board is questionable.
Since success (a fully functional motherboard) is not guaranteed after replacing these two components, paying for such a repair attempt may not be worth the cost. Unless the repair can be attempted at no (or very low) labor cost, you may have to write off this hardware.

ADDENDUM

... but I just found another capacitor and another unidentified "chip" to be burned as well

That indicates that the board failure is more complicated. Without a schematic for this circuit board, you don't know how all of these components interact with each other, and which was the initial failure that triggered the other failures. It's starting to look like an unrepairable board (unless you like to tinker).

Thank you very much, after I put the capacitor under a microscope, it’s clear that the side of the weld material of the capacitor close to the IC is burned out, the damage does not seems to be effecting the motherboard surface as I can scratch the color change off and the surface will show normal color. Do you think I still need to replace the IC? As it’s much easier to just replace the capacitor.

Then you could try simply replacing that capacitor. Beware that the failure of the capacitor could be the secondary effect of some other (primary) failure. IOW after replacement, the cap may fail again. Determining the replacement value may be tricky. If you don't have a capacitance meter or if it's unmeasurable, the physical dimensions may be an indicator. Take a look at https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256807095684519.html

Thanks for the remaind, but I just found another capacitor and another unidentified "chip" to be burned as well, I updated the post to add the picture

Note that the unidenfied "chip" is the last picture, and the second capacitor I found to be broken is the second last picture. It's suppose to be a IC as well according to the PCB component naming system(I added the system to the post)
